# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date Convert String to Timestamp

Tags: java, parsing, date

I want to convert a String containing a date to Timestamp.

My String is something like this: 2014-06-10T03:03

What I try to do:

```
Date startDate = null, endDate = null;

    try {
        startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(fromDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .parse(toDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-06-10T03:03".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not have the seconds in your DateString(**"2014-06-10T03:03"**), you need to remove the pattern for seconds (**":ss"**) from the format as well.

```
 startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
```